# jq: how to convert to number if possible, but leave as is, if not?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, type-conversion, jq

How can I create some_function in jq that will convert to number if possible, but leave as is if not? e.g.:

```
echo '["123","12x3"]' | jq '.[] | some_function'
```

would return

```
123
"12x3"
```

The tonumber() function would work fine, if only I could have some fallback in the event of an error. A couple potential solutions could either be to allow error handling e.g. iferror(xxx, result_if_error), or to have some sort of "safe" tonumber() function, but I can't find a way to get either solution to work in jq.

For the error handling approach, I also tried:

```
echo '["123","12x3"]' | jq 'map(try tonumber catch .) '
```

(as well as the equivalent as a user-defined function) to no avail. I'm guessing there is an easy solution to this problem but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply write: `tonumber? // .`

Or as a function:

```
def tonumberq: tonumber? // .;
```

Comment: Could you expand on that? I'm not sure how to use it: `echo '{"a":"1","b":"world"}' | jq 'map_values(tonumber? // .)'` produces the output {"b":"world"}
```

Comment: @LucianWischik -  There's a nasty bug that stops ? working properly with map_values as defined in builtin.jq. Use this def instead: `def map_values(f): with_entries(.value = (.value|f));`